# Connect to windows EC2 instance through java code without SMB protocol

Tags: java, windows, smb, winrm, cifs

I'm trying to connect AWS Windows instance through java code with CIFS or WinRM and I don't have to use SMB protocol. **I'm not sure whether is possible or not**.

On instance WinRM service is running and for testing I have allowed all traffic as inbound to instance.

I want to copy some file on this instance as well as I want to run some bash script using this java code.

I have tried  [xebialabs/overthere](https://github.com/xebialabs/overthere)  with CIFS.

Following code base I tried to achieve but facing some issue with this (All host properties are there)

```
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

    options.set(ConnectionOptions.OPERATING_SYSTEM, OperatingSystemFamily.WINDOWS);
    options.set(CifsConnectionBuilder.CONNECTION_TYPE, CifsConnectionType.WINRM_INTERNAL);
    options.set(CifsConnectionBuilder.WINRM_TIMEMOUT, "PT172800.000S");
    options.set(ConnectionOptions.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 900000);
    options.set(ConnectionOptions.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 900000);
    options.set(CifsConnectionBuilder.WINRM_ENABLE_HTTPS, false);
    options.set(CIFS_PORT, CIFS_PORT_DEFAULT);
    options.set(ConnectionOptions.PROTOCOL, CIFS_PROTOCOL);

    // Host Properties
    options.set(ConnectionOptions.ADDRESS, host);
    options.set(ConnectionOptions.USERNAME, user);
    options.set(ConnectionOptions.PASSWORD, password);

    AddressPortMapper mapper = DefaultAddressPortMapper.INSTANCE;
    OverthereFile workingDirectory = null;
    WinrsConnection connection = new WinrsConnection(options, mapper, workingDirectory);

    connection.connect();
```

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create a smb:winrm_native connection with a winrs proxy that is not running Windows
>       at com.xebialabs.overthere.winrs.WinrsConnection.connect(WinrsConnection.java:89)
>       at ot.WinRmUtils.getWinRmConnection(WinRmUtils.java:76)
>       at ot.WinRmUtils.getNewWinRMConnection(WinRmUtils.java:89)
>       at ot.OtPOC.main(OtPOC.java:16)

I have also tried [cloudsoft/winrm4j](https://github.com/cloudsoft/winrm4j) But this is also not working.

Comment: Why you do not use just SMB to connect to the Windows machine?

Comment: Due to some security reasons I'm trying to remove SMB,  This is POC where I'm trying to use something else without SMB to connect windows machine.

Comment: First of all only SMBv1 has the major security issue, SMBv2 has the man in the middle issue bot SMBv3 is safe and you can use it. my suggestion is to use SMB if you want to connect Windows machines because its native.

For java SMBv2 support you have the SMBj (open source, and there are couple of more open source produces)
For SMBv3 support you have the jNQ (commercial license)

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration you're configuring `CifsConnectionType.WINRM_INTERNAL`, whereas you're instantiating a `WinrsConnection`. Prefer to use the factory method `Overthere.getConnection(CifsConnectionBuilder.CIFS_PROTOCOL, config)`, or instantiate the `WinrmConnection` directly.

The `WinrsConnection` (or the `CifsConnectionType.WINRM_NATIVE`) is only suitable for Windows-2-Windows connections, as that uses the `winrs.exe` command to execute the WinRM commands.

The `WinrmConnection` (or the `CifsConnectionType.WINRM_INTERNAL`) is suitable for all connections as that is implemented fully in Java.